# Programmatic constraints

Tags: ios, swift

I thought I was doing this correctly, adding addItemButton to self.view before trying to activate the constraints, but it's throwing up this error:

'Unable to activate constraint with anchors  and  because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

```
var addItemButton: UIButton{
    let button = UIButton()
    let dim: CGFloat = 64.0

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dim, height: dim)
    button.tintColor = Constants.color4
    button.layer.cornerRadius = dim / 2
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true

    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return button
}

extension MainViewController{
func setupView(){
    view.addSubview(itemsCollectionView)

    view.addSubview(addItemButton)
    addItemButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    addItemButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
}
```

I thought view.addSubView(addItemButton) would create the necessary hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var addItemButton: UIButton {` is a computed variable. Everytime you access it, a new button instance is created, therefore in

```
view.addSubview(addItemButton)
addItemButton.centerXAnchor. ...
```

The `addItemButton` on every line is a new object. One button is created and then you are trying to add constraints to a completely different button.

You should convert the variable to a `lazy` one, initialized from a closure:

```
lazy var addItemButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    let dim: CGFloat = 64.0

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dim, height: dim)
    button.tintColor = Constants.color4
    button.layer.cornerRadius = dim / 2
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true

    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()
```